# Why is my global variable not passing the value?

Tags: javascript, cordova, scope

I am trying to save the path to an image taken with the camera into a db using Phonegap API. I think I am maybe making a mistake with the scope as I can't understand why userPic would be undefined when I select all from users. I am using the same method to try store the name using getElement etc .value. I have been trying to find a resolution to this all day. I just can't figure it out.

```
    var imagePath; // global variable
```

In my camera success function

```
    var placeImage = document.getElementById('placeImage');//Gets the imageholder
placeImage.src = imageURI;//gives image source the 
    placeImage.style.display = 'block';
imagePath=placeImage.src;// assigns the imageURI to imagePath
console.log(imageURI);// this is logging a path to the image file// etc
```

and then in my insert into db function

```
    var userPic=imagePath;
```

...

```
    dbtx.executeSql(insertRec, [theName, userPic], queryDB, insFail);
```

Comment: Where are you doing `var userPic = imagePath`? Can we see more of the code?

Comment: It should. Is `placeImage.src` valid? Can you `alert(placeImage.src)` ?

Comment: Is it possible that your database code is *outside* the "camera success function", and that it runs *before* the success function has been executed?

Comment: Full code here http://jsfiddle.net/Inkers/xdAYs/

Comment: @Ondra The placeImage.src is alerting the path to the image after the camera returns the pic.

Comment: Can you put a log statement in `function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)` and confirm that imageURI has a value?

Comment: There is already a console.log(imageURI); there and is working.

Comment: jsfiddle isn't letting me run your code, but something seems weird in the insertRecord function where you define userPic in the signature and then define a variable called userPic.  I would expect this to work but maybe your browser is getting confused.  Can you do something like `var myPic = userPic || imagePath`

Comment: Hi Dough, It won't let you fun the code in fiddle because of the camera functionality. I am testing on an Android device. I just put the code in fiddle as way to show it all quickly. I think that adding an || or will just create more confusion. I fail to see the benefit.

Comment: @Pointy My database code is indeed outside the camera success function. I am establishing a connection to the db in ondeviceready, the insertrecord is called by the save button so shouldn't fire until the fields, including the photo, has a value. At least I think that is how I have set it up? My issue is more about passing the path from one to the other. I am new to all this and struggling with understanding params scope etc. I think that is where the issue lies.